# Verify authenticity of the Star Wars Snowtrooper minifig

Tags: minifigures, star-wars

I recently acquired a number of Lego Star Wars minifigures from an online seller who's looking to dispose his full collection. However, after I bought some of them and carefully inspected each part at home, I get rather confused...

1. Helmet - There's no "LEGO" logo anywhere in the helmet. Is that legit?
2. Faces - All are black, round, with no "LEGO" anywhere. Is this legit too?
3. Torso - Only what seems to be "LEGO" on the stud connecting to the head that's somewhat "punched" in the middle. Legit?
4. Feet - 2 of them have the "LEGO" on the left feet, and 1 has both feet with "LEGO". 2 of the "LEGO" in the centre area do not have the copyright icon, and 1 has. Too many "LEGO"s also suspicious?
5. Weapon - This is the one that got me most confused. These 3 do not have the "LEGO" word on them, but there's a copyright icon and number on the side. They are numbered 2, 5, and 7. I can't make any sense here. So are they legit?

Sincerely looking forward to help please....
P.S. I'm restricted to posting only 2 pictures *.*"

[image: Weapon - with copyright icon]
[image: Weapon - with "number"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to be certain without some more pictures or information to narrow down when these minifigs were produced, but it sounds like what you have are some of the older Snowtroopers with the helmet and backpack attached in a single piece. Based on that assumption and the details you provided, I think you are looking at authentic Lego, with the possible exception of the blasters.

Point by point:

1. I couldn't find a LEGO logo in any of my helmets, but it did look like there was a copyright icon in the central anti-stud.
2. Many of the older snow/storm/clone troopers have blank, black heads. The ones that do not have a solid central stud hole (but a triangular arrangement of holes) do not have a LEGO logo.
3. Your description matches my torsos. All have the LEGO logo on the top of the neck stud, somewhat obscured by what I assume is where the mold injected the plastic.
4. The legs all sound legitimate to me. I was able to find minifigs that matched the variations you describe.
5. These seem suspect. I was unable to find any in my collection that matched these patterns of printing. In all of mine, there was printing in the recessed "bolt" section of the barrel. None of them had printing on the trigger section.

Comment: 1. I will check the helmet again carefully for the copyright icon. 2. Yes, you're right, the central hole is made up of triangular holes, so confirmed legit. 3. Torsos legit too :). 4. Legs legit! :D 5. Argh this is the bad part, how am I gonna get the blasters replaced man

Comment: Your best bet for getting new blasters is either [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58247&name=Minifig,%20Weapon%20Gun,%20Blaster%20Short%20(SW)&category=%5BMinifig,%20Weapon%5D#T=C) or [BrickOwl](http://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-black-minifig-gun-short-blaster-58247).

Comment: Out of the 3 helmets, only 1 of it has a copyright icon in the anti-stud :O that said, the 3 of them do look exactly similar no matter which angle I compared them from, side by side. How I wish I can send more pictures here, arghhh. And hi again, and thank you so much for the links, I will get my authentic blasters!

Comment: Looks like my blasters -.-@ https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58247&name=Minifig,%20Weapon%20Gun,%20Blaster%20Short%20(SW)&category=%5BMinifig,%20Weapon%5D#T=C

Comment: That particular copyright symbol is definitely a Lego mark. Not as obvious as the word Lego, of course, but in my experience (including lots of Lego knockoffs bought second-hand), it's never been on anything but Lego.